# ASP.NET Without Project File

Tags: asp.net

I've got a ASP.NET project without the .proj file. How do I recreate the project file, so I can work on it on my machine?

Is this possbile?

Comment: I have such solution, without proj file, but it is Web Service solution, asp net asmx. Btw I don't know how to see nuget references there since there is no project node in the Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you sure it's not a Web Site Project, as opposed to a Web Application Project? Web Site projects do not have project files - you open a folder rather than a project file. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730880%28VS.80%29.aspx#wapp_topic5) for the differences between the two.

To check, each page of a Web Application project will have a .aspx, a .aspx.cs and a .aspx.designer.cs, whereas the Web Site project pages don't have the designer files.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new project and then you can use the "Add Existing Item" and add each of your files (you can select multiple files).

EDIT:
Or your can drag and drop the files into the "Solution Explorer"

Comment: cool. Is there any other way? Or should I ask for the project file from the author.

Comment: I would certainly ask for the project file from the author. That would be preferable.

Comment: ...unless it is a web site project.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to run VS2005 SP1 or later. In VS2005, they removed the project file. They reintroduced it again in SP1.

If you don't have a project file, your project is called a "Web Site". If you have a project file, it's a "Web Application". One difference between the two is also that in a web application, you compile all code-behind files to a single .dll. In a web site, each code behind file goes in its own dll (or are compiled dynamically at runtime)

I believe that if you right click the project in solution explorer, there is a "Convert To Web Application" menu item.

Note, you must rename the App_Code folder to something else, otherwise it will be compiled both at compile time, and at runtime.

Personally I much prefer web applications to web sites